# Login with token authentication SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, api, authentication, token

I get confused how to make a login session with token authentication? I already have the token authentication but still confuse how to implement that for calling the API. If you guys have some recommendation, please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the flow is the following

- You call your "login" method in the API with your credentials
- The API gives back a token string
- You save that token to a database or keychain or somewhere else
- On your following calls (getDataFromAPI) you include this token in your request header via the method which is required in your API For example ["Authorization: "yourTokenString"] or  ["Authorization: "bearer (yourTokenString)"] or in a parameter dictionary if it is JSON RPC